# Referenced assembly, formerly unsigned, now signed, cannot be loaded by application

Tags: reflection, dll, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution

After signing and recompiling a referenced assembly (MyAssembly.dll), my web application fails with "The located assembly's manifest definition with name MyReferencedAssembly does not match the assembly reference".

This is what I expected, since the PublicKeyToken has changed from null to a new key.

It seems you should be able to use an assemblyBinding section in the web.config file to make the application use the new signed assembly.

Problem is, there doesn't seem to be a way to identify the assembly the app will be looking for (the old, unsigned assembly) in the assemblyIdentity element.

Since the old publicKeyToken value was null, I've tried leaving it out, tried setting it to an empty string, null in quotes and none of them seem to work.

I've tried changing the version number so I can use binding Redirect from the old to the new version, and also tried setting a specific codeBase for the assembly.

All of this fails so I have to believe the assembly loading process just doesn't like loading a signed assembly when an unsigned one was referenced/expected.

How do I perform this mapping?

Recompiling the entire code base referencing the signed assemblies is not an option.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Using binding redirect is not an option, recompiling is required.